# Dynamic radial circle in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, xml

Why is it so difficult to make this little thing work? : /

I want to create something like android's lock screen.
I have an XML:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

<stroke
    android:width="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:color="@color/black" />  

<gradient
    android:type="radial"
    android:startColor="@color/green"
    android:endColor="@color/red"
    android:gradientRadius="@dimen/dp_50" />

</shape>
```

This circle is a background of a TextView, so the following happens:
1. wrap_content creates a little circle in the center of the screen
2. fill_parent creates an elipse taking the whole screen, instead of a circle
In addition I would like to change the startColor and endColor programmatically - Didn't find any documentations\threads which solved this **SIMPLE** issue.

Comment: call View.getBackground() to get a Drawable of your TextView, then see what kind of Drawable it is and see the docs about that Drawable class

Comment: I actually did my little research. I know there is GradientDrawable, ShapeDrawable, RadialGradient but nothing works :S

Comment: what "norhing works" ?

Comment: As far as I know, I can't change the color programmatically without creating 2 different objects (which makes my app kind of static one).   And of course there is the thing that the circle is very small with the "wrap_contant" or it expands the whole screen (making an elipse) with the "fill_parent" - All I want is one circle in the middle of the screen with radial gradient in it, which I can change programmatically :)

Comment: did you try to create and set GradientDrawable?

Comment: Yep..The "setColors" method was added in API 16!!..Too late to think about this basic method LOL..I'm working with API 10

Comment: are you going to change colors 50 times per second? if not just create a new instance and pass the colors in ctor

Comment: I can do this, but I have to "configure" the object with all the atts I need (shape, colors, gradient type etc) --> The xml worth nothing if I create new object every time